# I receive a message from one extension script to another, I can alert() the message, but I can't assign it to any variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm sending a string message from background.js to popup.js. I do receive a message in popup.js but I can't manipulate it. I am able to view it if a alert() it or if I assign it to innerHTML of a popup.html element, but I can't assign it to any variables in popup.js so I could modify it and make use of it.

I tried regular assignment, I tried using substring() to copy the message into another variable

Here I have a piece of background.js that sends a message to popup.js. myString is a string:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: myString
});
```

Here is a piece of popup.js that receives the message once background.js is executed, the code below works, it displays the string in popup.html:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
container.innerHTML = request.source;}})
```

This also works:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
alert(request.source);}})
```

But when I try to assign it to a variable, I get nothing (testString is still empty):

```
var testString = '';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
testString = request.source;}})
```

If I assign a value to testString outside of chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(...), the assignment works just fine, testString ends up being "abcde":

```
var testString = '';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
console.log("do nothing")}});

testString = "abcde";
```

I want to have the contents of request.source in a variable so I could manipulate it.

Thank you.

Comment: You should manipulate it inside the callback, not outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` receives a callback as parameter and its return value does not come in a synchronous way. At the time you've received the message from background, the variable `testString` may be already assigned to `"abcde"` or any other value you try to assign to it after the addListener function.

You have to call another function (inside the addListener callback) which passes `testString` as parameter:

```js
var testString = '';

function onMessageReceived (source)  {
   testString = source
   // do whatever you want with the value
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  if (request.action === 'getSource') {
     onMessageReceived(request.source)
  }
})
```

Another option is to wrap the whole `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` inside a Promise:

```js
function onMessageReceived (source) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
      if (request.action === 'getSource') {
         resolve(request.source)
      }

      // don't forget to reject the Promise if some condition is not satisfied
  })
}

onMessageReceive().then(function (source) {
  // variable source contains request.source value
})
```